# New linux programmer

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

can someone explain to me what it means?

```
LOG=/etc/security/aixpert/log/aixpert.log
exec 1>>$LOG
exec 2>&1
```

I know that we are logging into a file... but what exactly it does? especially the `1`, `2`, `>&` and in general

Comment: They're redirection operators. A quick Google search should teach you more than any answer here can give you.

Comment: I did that, But i couldnt find for `1` and `2` and so got confused... I didnt know what they represented. Learnt now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`exec` manipulates *file descriptors*. In particular, you redirect file descriptor 1 (which corresponds to C's `stdout`) to the designated file on disk, and you redirect file descriptor 2 (`stderr`) to file descriptor 1.

So everything ends up getting written into the log file rather than being printed on the console.

Comment: but why the `>&` insted of `>>` ?

Comment: @footy: The `>&` designates another file descriptor; the `>>` designates a *file*.

Answer (score 2):

- 1>> redirects the general output to whatever is in $LOG, in this case a logfile (2 arrows meen "append")
- 2> redirects stderr, the general error messages, in this case to stream 1 (see above)
- exec makes all of this apply to the current shell, so all following commands are affected.